# How does type deduction work for evaluating expressions?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

I just did a clamp function using templates. It looks like this:

```
template <typename Tp_, typename Up_, typename Vp_>
inline auto clamp(Tp_ x, Up_ xmin, Vp_ xmax)
noexcept -> decltype(x < xmin ? xmin : (x > xmax ? xmax : x)) {
  return x < xmin ? xmin : (x > xmax ? xmax : x);
}

template <typename Tp_, typename Up_>
inline auto clamp(Tp_ x, const Up_ &v) -> decltype(clamp(x, min(v),
                                                         max(v))) {
  static_assert(is_iterable<Up_>::value,
                "The data set must be iterable");
  return clamp(x, min(v), max(v));
}
```

I have a unit test for testing that function that does this:

```
TEST(StatsTest, clamp) {
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(1, 0, 5), 1);
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(-1, 0, 3), 0);
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(15, 0, 3), 3);

  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(1, 0.f, 3.), 1);
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(-1, 0.f, 3.), 0.f);
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(15, 0, 3), 3.);

  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(543, v1), 543);
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(-143, v1), 71);
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(14143, v1), 977);
}
```

But when I think about it, that doesn't make sense: the result of `decltype(clamp(x, min(v), max(v)))` is not supposed to be known before the run time, is it ?

Just in case, I've tried to replace my test with some variables datas:

```
TEST(StatsTest, clamp) {
  int a = 0;
  float b = 65.3f;
  double c = 89.7;
  ASSERT_EQ(clamp(a, b, c), 65.3f);
}
```

But it still passes !

What is the explanation ?

Comment: `decltype` is a compile-time operator. It *must* be known before runtime.

Comment: @chris That's my point, how does the compiler know the result of such an expression ? If it can deduce the type of this expression, it seems to me that it can deduce the type of all expressions... Or at least all expressions with [if, else, lt, gt, etc.]

Comment: Types cannot depend on runtime values in C++. The language rules prevent that. That means the result of a conditional expression is the same regardless of whether the test is true or false. And yes, all expressions have a compile-time type.

Comment: There's a fairly complicated set of rules governing what type a conditional expression has, which is computed from the types of its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The type that `clamp` returns is the common type of the arguments, it is not the type of the argument that is selected.

You are then fooled by further promotions, making your equality checks hold.

`decltype( true?7:3.0 )` is the same type as `decltype( false?7:3.0 )`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot do this. The only reason this works in this case is because you are working with integer/floating point values that have default conversions. For example:

```
float f;
int y;
double z;
std::cin >> f;
std::cin >> y;
std::cin >> z;
auto p = clamp(f, y, z);
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), double>::value, "Not Double!");
```

This will work because all of the types given can be promoted to `double`. In general, if you tried to do this with types that do not have promotions like this, you would get a compile-time error, as the return type of a function must be known at compile time (of course it has to be, otherwise how would the compiler know how much space to allocate on the stack for the return value?).